# не выходит обернуть динамическую библиотеку, в технологический стандарт COM+

Tags: windows, dll, x86, x86-64

У меня LabVIEW не работает с библиотекой в виндус 64 битной , а в 32-битной работает. Библиотека 32 битная .

Решил "обернуть" библиотеку в технологический стандарт **COM+**.

Попробовал действовать по [информационному ресурсу который нашёл в интернете](https://www.sqit.ru/2016/05/com.html)

пытаюсь зарегистрировать DLL в системе.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получил такой результат .
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Чтож придется всё ручками :3

Через службу компонентов создаю приложение 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создаю новое библиотечное приложение 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Создаю компонент и мне выдаёт вот это (когда выбираю .dll):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень печальный результат, что я делаю не так ???

Comment: Рецепт превращения обычной DLL в COM-сервер, на который вы дали ссылку, это полная бредятина. Человек явно переписал это откуда-то обрывком, не понимая что он собственно переписывает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-то у вас все в кучу: LabView, 32-битные и 64-битные DLL и COM+

1. 64-битные приложения не могут загружать 32-битные библиотеки. COM+ не поможет исправить эту проблему.
2. 32-битное приложение (в том числе на 64-битной ОС) может нормально загружать 32-битные DLL.
3. С помощью regsvr32 можно зарегистрировать только саморегистрируемую библиотеку COM-объектов, а не произвольную DLL.

Если LabView не может загрузить какую-то библиотеку, надо решать эту проблему, а не бросаться что-то регистрировать в COM+. Обычно загрузка DLL падает если одна из ее зависимых DLL не найдена или не той разрядности. Используя программы вроде Process Monitor можно отследить, к чему именно идет обращение при загрузке DLL и с какой именно ошибкой оно падает.